# How to install video driver in Debian?

Tags: debian, opengl

I have an old computer with an ATI Radeon 1150. I installed Debian but I don't have a driver for hardware accelerated OpenGL.

What should I do?

Comment: Which driver are you using? Does that driver even have OpenGL support? How do you know this driver doesn't have OpenGL support?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to set up the proprietary ATI driver; exact instructions on how to do this in Debian can be found [here](https://wiki.debian.org/ATIProprietary).

Bear in mind that both AMD and nVidia tend to phase older cards out of their non-legacy driver in order to keep the size down, and from what I can see the 1150 is at least six years old; as far as I can see even the 'legacy' variant of the driver only goes back to the 2000 series...